# Vendor specific MIME as Content-Type in incoming WCF REST POST request (e.g. application/vnd.company+xml)

Tags: .net, wcf, rest

I struggle finding the solution for having an incoming POST request hit my service declaration  unless the generic "application/xml" or "application/json" is set as Content-Type of the  request:

Since we're using custom MIME types, e.g. "application/vnd.company+xml", this should really be the value of the Content-Type header. But clearly WCF cannot derive the request format from this. Does anyone know of a solution for this?

In short: I'd like

```
Content-Type: application/vnd.company+xml, and
Content-Type: application/vnd.company+json
```

to map the incoming POST request to XML and JSON respectively, but as of now, the service will only respond when I issue the POST request with

```
Content-Type: application/xml, or
Content-Type: application/json
```

Platform is .NET4 and WCF.

Comment: You don't have to use custom media types to describe your messages, just use JSON-LD with a REST specific RDF vocabulary and with your application specific vocabulary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use WCF Web API instead of WCF REST.  One of the main advantages is that it gives you the flexibility to use any media type you want.

If you are really stuck with WCF REST in .net 4, then change your request parameter to stream type.  That will allow you to POST whatever data you want.  You will need to take care of the deserialization yourself.

Comment: Thanks, Darrel. But Web API is still in preview. Would you use it in production code? Regarding a WCF REST/.NET4 solution, would it be possible to stick on a behavior to sniff the Content-Type header and set the RequestFormat to WebMessageFormat.Xml/Json respectively?

Comment: I would use WCF Web API in production code before WCF REST.  If you know WCF internals really well, you might be able to do the switch but I wouldn't try it personally.

Comment: Thanks again, Darrel. I went for the stream type after all. Not only can we work with content types of our own choice, but the manual deserialization also puts us in control of the faults returned to the client, say, if invalid data types or non-well-formed XML is posted to our services.