# WCF Rest Stream accepting any content type

Tags: wcf, http, header, stream, content-type

My WCF REST service method:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
Metadata[] Extract(Stream stream);
```

Is failing, and returing an error to the client indicating that the content type is incorrect.
The error message from WCF is "The remote server returned an error: (415) Missing Content Type.".

How do I accept a stream with any content type, and **not have to set the content-type** in the client. If I set the content type to application/octet-stream it works. I would ideally like the WCF method to accept the stream regardless of the content type.

Thanks.

Comment: _"I would ideally like the WCF method to accept the stream regardless of the content type."_ And have WCF guess what to do with the data it receives? Content-types aren't invented for nothing. ;) Can't you make your client standards compliant?

Comment: The content types are being detected by Tika. That's the whole point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967741/vendor-specific-mime-as-content-type-in-incoming-wcf-rest-post-request-e-g-app) - you need to use the [WCF Web API](http://wcf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WCF%20HTTP) to get low-level access to the request or use a request parameter that [supports streaming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx) (MTOM).

Comment: Thanks sliver, I was hoping for a workaround, I will just force the use of application/octet-stream. It seems like a catch all content type.